# Rounding some numbers, and converting some to int

Tags: ruby, integer, rounding

I made a method that takes two numbers and returns a calculated value rounded to three decimals. I'm curious to know how I can have numbers such as `1.141` to be rounded but numbers like `5.0` turned into integers (`5`).

code:

```
def calculateHypotenuse(a,b)
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0)
      return raise 
    end
    c = Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b))
    return c.round(3)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure there is a built in function for floats, but a hackish way could be something like this.

```
def conditional_truncation(x)   
  x.truncate == x ? x.truncate : x
end

conditional_truncation(1.141)
 => 1.141
conditional_truncation(5.0)
 => 5
```